# Generate random number serverside every minute

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a system where a random number is generated (www.DivergentMC.com/genauth) every minute server side. So if you refresh it remains the same until the server counts one minute and serversode makes a new one for everyone to see.

Comment: Are there any efforts? Any useful **code**, that you could supply here?

Comment: I'm no good at php, but I have looked around for how to do this. Its so I can get a python script to read the page to get the authcode.

Comment: Either use a scheduled task, or offload the work onto the first request every minute.

Comment: Have you tried something? Please provide us your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Cron Job for it. Save this generated number to file or db:

```
file_put_contents('randomNumber.txt', rand(0, 9999));
```

Comment: Do I have to include /public_html/ in the path?

Comment: @ConnorMcFarlaneConnorMcF If you wish to put file where your script is located, than no, else include full path

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  $rand = rand();
  $now = time();
  $next = strtotime(date("H:i",strtotime("+1 minute")));
  $diff = $next-$now;
  if(!$_COOKIE['random']) {
    setcookie("random",$rand,time()+$diff);
  } else {
    $rand = $_COOKIE['random'];
  }
  echo $rand;
?>
```

Comment: I need it to be serverside random, so everyone sees the same number.

Comment: Then you need to use cron that will save the random number to a file (or db).